# Is there a way to restrict network access to a partition/drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, internet-connection, internet-security, restrictions

Well I was just asking myself if there's a way to isolate a harddrive either physically, or a drive/partition via software from any outside connection.

Like, the drive would be invisible for any possible intruder, because it's simply not online - while the rest of the pc is.

I'm just wondering if it can be done.

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: No;  The way an outside intruder gains access to information is by compromising an account that has access to the information, your information would have to be accessible by nobody, in order to protect it from everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of attacks coming not directly over network, but allowed by users when they downloading malicious attachments either from emails or picking it from malicious or hacked web sites. Since malicious content would run under the same account, all permissions you have will be inherited by virus or in other words, - if you able to see the drive you want to protect then any program you run can do the same.

If you want to protect some drive/partitions, you need to use separate user's accounts. This way you can remove from drive you want to protect all permissions except one user that allowed to access it. Use additional user account for browsing and other stuff that need online access and use dedicated for that particular drive separate user who got access permission to access that "secure" drive. Must important thing is that all users accounts of your computer should be standard one(restricted) otherwise if they have administrator's account permissions it would be useless. Use administrators account only for administrative tasks and never use it for a regular tasks.